Can a belly landing stop more slowly than a regular landing? If so, why?
I read on the Wikipedia page about the Jeju Air Flight 2216 crash today:

The aircraft overshot the runway and struck an embankment holding the ILS array while attempting a belly landing after its front landing gear failed to deploy at Muan International Airport.

This makes me wonder, regardless of that specific incident: Can a belly landing stop more slowly than a regular landing? If so, why?
I looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belly_landing but didn't find any answer there.

It depends on the friction coefficient between the runway and the aircraft.
Tires (as long as they are not slipping as in a normal landing) can go somewhere from 0.5 to 0.8 (depending on the runway conditions) maximum - the real force is determined in the cockpit. In normal operations you want to break as little as possible to reduce the wear on the brakes.
This is static friction. Sliding friction will be much lesser and will vary significantly on many condition.
Metal on asphalt can be assumed in the 0.3 to 0.1 range - even less when even slightly wet.
The next problem is, this is not linear - it roughly follows a 1/x curve, so a lower braking action will significantly increase the distance required.
So it much depends on the individual situation if a belly landing has a longer or shorter distance then a normal landing.

The use of lift spoilers/air breaks/flaps influences the deceleration. The actual touch down point determines how much asphalt is available to slow down the aircraft before it slides on grass. Both factors played a role in the referenced case, but we don't know wether hydraulics power was available and where the aircraft landed.

I'm going with liquid (melted) aluminum as a lubricant.  +1 for stating a wide (and unpredictable) coefficient for belly landing.

There's also the fact that you probably don't have thrust reversers during a belly landing,  since they usually won't deploy until after the gear compress from weight landing on them (and many types of reverser would be unreliable or actively torn off in this scenario anyway).

Yes.  If the nose is held up friction drag may be reduced to a level less than "normal" brakes and reverse thrusters.
Airliner brakes can hold against the full thrust of the aircraft on a dry clean runway surface, as long as they do not overheat.  Spoilers also assist in slowing down a normal landing.

One might graph drop in friction coefficient drop with the onset on (friction) melting aluminum.  (Did you all ever see what an icecube does on a hot griddle?)

If brakes are holding the wheels stationary, there is no movement, so no friction, so no heat being generated. The tires could possibly skid, but if the brakes start out cold, they don't get hot by holding the aircraft stationary. They get hot by slowing a moving aircraft.

Well Ralph, we have now arrived at the concensus that motion heating metal (or what ever any friction brake is made out of) may start to degrade its performance (landing brakes are also "cold").  Heat generated (by the aircraft skidding on its belly or by braking) will be proportional to energy taken out of the aircraft (by slowing it).  And just as brake performance degrades when heated, so will the belly braking performance degrade --> catastrophically, when it begins to melt.  I dare say aluminum melts at a lower temperature than brake rotors.
